# Create references in R

Tags: r, reference, ref

I used the package "ref" for creating and using references to objects such as data frames (see sample code part below). That worked really good.
But now I switched over to the new R version and when trying to install the package there is an error saying this package is not available for R version 3.5.0.

Is there any other package or function to achieve referencing? Or is there a workaround for usage of the "ref" package under 3.5.0?

```
...
for (sOneDfIntervResultName in listDfIntervResultNames) {

   #add new row if not existant
   dfRef <- ref(sOneDfIntervResultName)
   deref(dfRef)[nrow(deref(dfRef))+1, ] <- NA

   #write start and end interval datetime
   deref(dfRef)$Interv_StartDatetimeUTC[nrow(deref(dfRef))] <- startIntervalDateTime
   deref(dfRef)$Interv_EndDatetimeUTC[nrow(deref(dfRef))] <- endIntervalDateTime
}
...
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful comment. I did not intend to give a reproducible example but just a excerpt of the code to help understand my question.

Comment: Have a look at the `data.table` package that manipulates data frames by reference

Comment: Thank you, I will have a closer look to that package.